# Error session_start(): Failed to read session data: redis PHP / Redis

Tags: php, session, redis

I am using PHP (7.2.30) with Redis as the session handler. Everything works great, sessions are saved to Redis, but rarely I will see the following error:

```
Error session_start(): Failed to read session data: redis (path: example.com:6379)
```

I am using PHPs built in session handling as follows.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['something'] = 'value';
```

Any advice on how to track down the cause?

Comment: Which version of PHP?

Comment: This github issue seems related - https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/1626

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Updated question: Php version 7.2.30. The problem is that it works 99% of the time, just fails sometimes... Im wondering if the session has expires on Redis, but the session cookie is still set

Comment: Which version of redis do you use? [This website](https://www.dragonbe.com/2016/12/sessions-in-php-71-and-redis.html) states they had the same issue and resolved it by downgrading from 3.1.0 to 3.0.0.

Comment: Redis version: 5.0.6, PHP-Redis version 4.3.0 (https://pecl.php.net/package/redis)